# Measuring low resistance (0.1 Ω range)

Tags: analog, resistance, resistance-measurement

The application is to light up numbers of LEDs depending on the measured resistance, eg. 1 LED for 0.1 Ω / 2 LEDs for 0.2 Ω.

I'm quite new to circuitry so I'm thinking of using four terminal sensing to get the voltages dropped at the load, and turn on the LEDs based on the voltage differences.

Comment: Yes it is possible. It is complicated, and will require a lot of components, but it is possible. Kelvin sensing could be used, but depends on how accurate you want the reading. Why are you avoiding the use of an MCU? Using one would make it a lot eaiser.

Comment: If you want accuracy, you need a proper ADC and MCU.

Comment: @Zephr We need a lot more details about your question to be able to answer it. If you tell us why you aren't using an MCU, why you think kelvin sensing is required, how you plan to display the range via LEDs and give us a lot more information, we can answer it with more details. As it stands, the answer is "yes" for the first question and "maybe" for the second. Without more information, your question will be closed.

Comment: "Kelvin sensing" and "MCU" and "LED display" are different questions. Yes, you can measure milliohm values with or without Kelvin sensing, and yes you can measure milliohm values with or without an MCU. An MCU is normally used to drive an LCD display: that would be difficult without an MCU.

Comment: @ElectronSurf for all the OP's question is worth, there is no given requirement for accuracy or even precision.

Comment: @tobalt There's an *if* in my comment.

Comment: @tobalt there's also no mention of the range: 100 LEDs on for 10 Ohm? 1000 LEDs for 100 Ohm? :D

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you could use an old-school 3-1/2 digit CMOS meter chip such as the [ICL7107](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ICL7106-ICL7107.pdf) (LED) or ICL7106 (LCD) and a few resistors. The ADC reference voltage would best be derived ratiometrically (proportional to sense current) so the reading is directly related to the ratio of unknown to know resistance (voltage drops out of the equation).

If you don't want to have currents like 1A flowing through the unknown , a modern 'zero-drift' instrumentation amplifier would allow a lower sense current current (though a gain of, say, 100 would mean a resolution of 1uV so the least significant digit will likely be worthless due to noise and DC offset, so there are limits). At 100mA you could have 1mΩ resolution in a 0~1.999 ohm scale without the amplifier, just the meter chip. The 710x chips have auto-zero and have fully differential high-impedance input voltage and reference inputs so they are ideal for this application.

Kelvin (4-wire) sensing would be important to accuracy unless  you have a very controlled setup with very low resistances. This really depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

To get a reading of exactly 10 levels of 0.1 Ω each, an [LM3914](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3914.pdf) will do by itself, paired with a 200 ± 10 mA (or higher) current source, which can be 2-3 transistors in a traditional current source configuration.  Since a voltage reference is handy, a current mirror style would suffice (but not much current is available from it, so a 3rd transistor to boost current seems likely).

The rationale behind this current is, the LM3914 is an array of comparators, with maximum 15 mV input offset; therefore to get a reliable reading per step, say 20mV is required, and (20 mV) / (0.1 Ω) = 200 mA.

Add a diff amp in front to reduce the voltage range required, and therefore current as well.  Using contemporary components such as LM358 with its 4 mV input offset, an improvement of about fivefold is easily had; a chopper/autozero type can safely reduce the reading to fractional mV, and thus perhaps only a mA for the test current.

If this is to be a battery powered device, the test current doesn't need to be on any longer than required to acquire a reading; a pulsed source, combined with an analog sample-and-hold, could be used to reduce supply current and power dissipation.

Other considerations include filtering (for RFI immunity), transient (ESD) protection, and perhaps cross-wiring protection; and maybe other general things, like battery charge indication/protection, charging circuit, etc. if applicable.

Anything more complicated than an LM3914 (which is itself nearly obsolete*) very rapidly collides with the ease -- and lower cost, and much greater performance -- of an MCU based solution.

*It's only available now (current production) in PLCC; an SOIC version I think was never made.  DIP is discontinued, but old stock is likely to remain available for many years.

Answer (score 0):

A measuring device (without the requirements of a *precision* instrument) could employ a humble low-cost **current-sense amplifier** so that even with a relatively small current you can get a clean result.

A simple [INA181A3](https://www.ti.com/product/INA181) has a voltage gain of 100V/V, so if you generate a constant current of say 50 mA, you'll have 5 mV over 0.1 Ohm, amplified to a decent 0.5 V. That will become 1 V with 0.2 Ohm, so very clean and distinct, still with a not-so-high driving current.

Remaining in the field of a rough measurement, you can obtain it with a series 100 Ohm 1/2 W resistor from a 5V power supply. That won't be a *constant current* source, but relative to your 0.1-0.2 Ohm measurement it will be good enough.

You can then decide to switch your 1-2 LED indication with any comparator, feed the voltage to an MCU, etc.